# Repeat last command N times

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

Short of writing a loop, is there a way to repeat the last command N times.

For example, I can repeat the last command once by using a double bang (!!), but how do I repeat it say 30 times?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `zsh`, and provided the last command line was only one command or pipeline or and-or list (that is for instance `echo x`, `echo x | tr x y`, `echo x && echo y`, even compound commands like `{ x; y; }` or `for`/`while` loops but not `echo x; echo y`):

```
repeat 30 !!
```

To repeat the previous command line even if it contained several commands, use:

```
repeat 30 do !!; done
```

Or:

```
repeat 30 {!!}
```

With `bash` and for simple-commands only (among the examples above, only the `echo x` case), you could define a helper function like:

```
repeat() {
  local n="$1"
  shift
  while ((n-- > 0)); do
    "$@"
  done
}
```

(and use `repeat 30 !!` like above). A side effect is that because the code will be running in a function, it  will see different `"$@"`, `"$#"` and things like `typeset` will work differently, so you can't do things like:

```
eval 'echo "$1"'
repeat 30 !!
```

Another approach to emulate `zsh`'s `repeat 30 {!!}` would be to declare an alias like:

```
alias repeat='for i in $(seq'
```

(assuming an unmodified `$IFS`)

And then use:

```
repeat 30); { !!; }
```

Answer (score 9):

The shortest I can come up with is:

```
date # or whatever command
for i in {1..30}; do !!; done
```

Comment: That has a loop.

Comment: You can shorten it to `for i in {1..30};{ !!;}`

Answer (score 3):

One approach could be to use the line editor to  insert `!!;` 30 times.

Like with `readline` (`bash`'s line editor) in `vi` mode:

```
!!;Escdd30p
```

The `emacs` mode equivalent does work with the `zsh` line editor but apparently not with `bash`'s `readline`. However you could use `readline` kbd macros instead which apparently can be repeated:

Define the kbd macro as `!!;`:

```
Ctrl+X(!!;Ctrl+X)
```

Which you can later invoke 30 times as:

```
Alt+3Alt+0Ctrl+Xe
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly, but:

```
 eval "`fc -ln -1`;: "{1..10}\;
```

The leading space is not strictly necessary, but is useful to suppress entering the `eval` command into history if `$HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace` (or `ignoreboth`).

Alternatively:

```
eval "fc -s $((HISTCMD-2)) "{1..10}\;
```

And:

```
eval 'history -s '{1..10}';fc -s -2;'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `seq` command is part of standard *nix and therefore not dependent on your shell.  Using it and your shell's loop construct you can do things like this:

`for i in $(seq 30); do !!; done`

or

`` for i in `seq 30`; do !!; done ``

Answer (score 0):

Another loop in bash (e.g. after this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372487/9689 )

Make it a executable file somewhere in your `$PATH` named `repeat` to achieve similar effect like in zsh (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372484/9689):

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$1
shift 1

for ((x=0; x<$n; ++x)); do
  "$@"
done
```

so later you can:

```
$ repeat 3 date
```

gist:
https://gist.github.com/gwpl/26fefe3a165304f3dedb21009506107f